# My code of conversion pdf to image only worked for me and not for my team (with imagick), i don't know why

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagick

I have a small script for creating jpg images from an uploaded multi-paged pdf file ($uploadfile) with Imagick:

```
for ($i=1; $i < $pages ; $i++) { 
    $image = new Imagick();
    $image->setResolution(300, 300);
    $image->readImage($uploadfile."[".$i."]");
    $image->setImageAlphaChannel(imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE);
    $image->mergeImageLayers(imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
    $image->setImageFormat('jpg');
    if ($image->writeImage($pathToImage."/".$pdf_name."0".$i.".jpg")) {
        echo "right <br>";
    }else{
        echo "NONE <br>";
    }
}
```

I have 2 problems

1. the code work great if i start conversion from 0, but not perfectly because it gives an error although it worked fine 
   `Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Failed to read the file'` 
   line mentioned
   `$image->readImage($uploadfile."[".$i."]");` and the error shows up only if i start from 0 
   so that i avoided the 0 index.
2. that small script works fine only for me, however my freind can't convert any pdf, it gives him a 503 error: 503 service unavailable

I need your help

Comment: Did you check $uploadFile permisions? maybe script doesn't have permissions to access that file.

Comment: Can you please provide more details about your suggestion, Thank you

Comment: What are the files in the `$uploadFile[$i]` folder? For 2, Give more details about the error.

Comment: @PrinceDorcis the $uploadFile is a PDF, the $i index means every single page of the PDF file, about Q2 that script bellow run corrctely for me, when my team have to test it, it gives them an error of server unavailable 503 and nothing shows up after